# Can we embed a specific Channel of slack Based on User Access onto Website?

Tags: asp.net, slack, slack-api

I want to embed a specific Channel feeds onto my website based on the user access to the channel of the Slack.

Can you please guide me if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of public channels a user is member of by calling [`users.conversations`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.conversations) with the respective user ID as parameter.

Note that this will not work for private channels:

> Private channel membership is only listed when the calling user, bot
>   user, or app shares membership in a direct message, multi-person
>   direct message, or private channel.